# Pointer to inner nodes of JSON (NSDictionary)

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
{
  "outterList": {
    "section1": {
      "entry1": {
        "value": ""
      },
      "entry2": {
        "value": ""
      },
      "entry3": {
        "value": ""
      },
      "innerSection": {
        "entry1": {
          "value": ""
        },
        "entry2": {
          "value": ""
        }
      }
    },
    "section2": {
      "entry1": {
        "value": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem statement** is to read the above json and store it back in the same format with the `"value"` fields updated as per the local logic.

I initially go and parse the above NSDictionary and convert it to an NSArray (Mutable), which holds all the `"entry"` nodes in a custom holder class.

Is it possible that my NSArray's holder object can store a direct pointer to `"outterList" -> "section1" -> "innerSection" -> "entry2"`, so that whenever I get a new value from my logic and I have to update it, I can do that immediately on the fly and not parsing it again to reach to that node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value in a dictionary will be changed if you modify the object itself:

```
myObj.value = newValue;
```

but it won't change if you simply assign pointer to another object:

```
myObj = [MyObj new];
```

so it won't work with JSON strings or numbers.

Also you can access dictionary values faster using valueForKeyPath like so:

```
[dict setValue:newValue forKeyPath:@"outterList.section1.entry1.value"]
```

Comment: @szhukav Can we use `forKeyPath` if the Dictionary has an Array. So may be like `section1` has an array of `entry`. So can I point to the second element in the array as  `outterList.section1.2.entry.value`

Comment: No, you can't pick specific array elements using valueForKeyPath as far as I know. So without any type checking it would look something like this: `[[[dict valueForKeyPath:@"outterList.section1"] objectAtIndex:2] valueForKeyPath:@"entry.value"]`. But It's not recommended to do so, since any change in the API will make your app crash.

Comment: Common approach is to keep all values in your custom classes and then parse them all to dictionary when you need to send JSON, which is done by a single method in some kind of a mapper pattern.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. I got a direction to solve this problem.
Many thanks!!